# How to solve functional equation $f(x+1)+f(x)=(f(x))^2+1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, functional-equations

I am looking for the solutions of the following functional equation:
$$f(x+1)+f(x)=(f(x))^2+1$$

For all non-negative integers $n$, we get a recurrence $f(n+1)+f(n)=(f(n))^2+1$. Suppose $f(0)=r$, then we have $f(1)=r^2-r+1, f(2)=r^4 - 2 r^3 + 2 r^2 - r + 1..$. etc. We may choose $r$ such that the sequence converges $\{f(n)\}_n$.

What to do next?

Comment: Notice that $f(x+1)+f(x)=f(x)^2+1$ is equivalent to $f(x+1)-f(x)=f(x)^2-2f(x)+1=[f(x)-1]^2=[f(x+1)-1]-[f(x)-1].$ Let $g(x)=f(x)-1,$ hence $\Delta{g}(x)=g(x)^2.$ This is one avenue for solving the equation. If using the shift operator is prefered, then $g(x+1)=g(x)^2+g(x)=h[g(x)],$ where $h(t)=t^2+t.$

Comment: @Angel I get it upto $g(x+1)=g(x)^2+g(x)$ but why you involve function $h$? How should I proceed with functional involving $g$?

Comment: I involve $h$ because $g(x+n)=h^n[g(x)],$ and this could be helpful information. I do not know how to solve the equation, but I known one can get that far. The function $h$ is simpler than the one you worked with.

Comment: Assume $f$ on $[0,1)$ arbitrary, then you can inductively extend it to $[1,2)$, $[2,3)$, ... and so to $[0,\infty)$ by the functional equation. You can start this process with an arbitrary half open interval of length $1$. You have to check if you can extend it in the other direction, towards $-\infty$, too.

Comment: @miracle173 What do you mean by asumming f  to  be arbitrary? What will be the expliicite form of $f$ on[0,1)

Comment: What miracle173 meant by "arbitrary" is you are free to choose ANY function $f$ on $[0.1)$, and your recursion formula will uniquely extend the function $f$ to all of $[0,\infty)$. The recursion formula does not put any restrictions on the value of $f$ in $[0,1)$. If you choose the values of $f$ on $[0,1)$ to be $\ge 1$, you can also use the recursion formula in reverse to define $f$ on $(-\infty, 0)$, though there it is not *uniquely* determined from the values on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose an arbitrary function
$$t:[0,1) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$$
then there is a unique function
$$f:[0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$$
such that
$$f|_{[0,1)}=t \tag1$$
and $$f(x+1)=(f(x))^2+1-f(x)\tag 2$$
Because if $x \in [0,\infty)$ then $x=n+\xi$, where $\xi \in [0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{{Z_0}^+}$. So
$$f(\xi)=t(\xi)\\f(1+\xi)=f(\xi)^2+1-f(\xi)\\
f(2+\xi)=f(1+\xi)^2+1-f(1+\xi)\\
\ldots\\
f(n+\xi)=f((n-1)+\xi)^2+1+f((n-1)+\xi)$$
So now we have calculated $f(x)=f((n-1)+\xi)$
Of course we can use an arbitrary half open interval of length $1$ to start with our definition of $f$.

But given such an half open interval of length, can we extend $f$ in a similar way towards $-\infty$? From the functional equation $(2)$ we have

$$f(x-1)=\frac{1+\sqrt{4x-3}}2\tag 3$$ or $$f(x-1)=\frac{1-\sqrt{4x-3}}2\tag 4$$
If $x>1$ then for $f(x-1)$ calculated by $(3)$ holds $$f(x-1)\ge 1,$$
too, so if $\xi \in [0,1)$ and $t(\xi)>1$ then $f(x)$ is defined for all $$x=\xi -n, n \in \mathbb{{Z_0}^{+}}$$

The investigation of other values of $\xi$ and  the formula $(4)$ is up to you.